# Batch classification of images in Tensorflow java

Tags: java, tensorflow

What's the best way to classify batch of images using TensorFlow java API? I also want the capability to resize the image in GPU so that all the images in the batch are of same dimension.

The only example I have found in the internet is for a single image , here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java .

In python , I see there is  a tf.stack method which allows to create a pack of tensors to create a batch request , I couldnt find anything equivalent to this method in java api.

I found an example of batch request which uses opencv and tensorflow https://medium.com/@alexkn15/tensorflow-and-javacv-591c1b9443a3.  Is there a better way to do this using standard tensor operations in java?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but in case you end up here, this is where you will now find the most up-to-date [training examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/java-models/tree/master/tensorflow-examples) with TensorFlow using Java.

There are based on the new [TF Java client](https://github.com/tensorflow/java) for TensorFlow 2.x, only available as snapshots for now but will become soon the official TensorFlow releases for Java.